# Set Private files to Public Amazon S3

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is it possible to convert from private s3 files in bucket to public using PHP library provided by Amazon AWS S3?

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is set the ACL to `public-read`, you can do this with the PHP SDK using the update_object() function.

```
$s3 = new AmazonS3();
$bucket = 'my-bucket' . strtolower($s3->key);

$response = $s3->update_object($bucket, 'test1.txt', array(
    'acl' => AmazonS3::ACL_PUBLIC
));
```

[Source](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/#m=AmazonS3/update_object)

Comment: thanks I did the same, after exploring the class! Thanks again!